# Issues with rendering handlebars views in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am facing an issue, that *res.render* does not render index view. View engine works, because I see that default layout is loaded, maybe some had same issue?

index.js

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
        extname: '.hbs',
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        helpers: "./lib/templates/helpers",
        partialsDir:"./lib/templates/partials",
        layoutsDir:"./lib/templates/layouts"
        });

    app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
    app.set('views', Path.join(__dirname, '/templates'));
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
      LandRoutes(app, req, res);
      next();
    })
```

register.js

```
const landRoutes = (app, req, res) => {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      return res.render("index")
    })
  }
```

default.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    {{> head }}
</head>
<div id="main">
     {{{content}}}
</div>
</html>
```

index.hbs

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="loader-wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

file structure:

```
lib/templates
             /helpers
             /layouts/default.hbs
             /partials
             /index.hbs
```

Thanks in an advance!